# Inserting a statement requiring minimum number of characters

Tags: php

Here I have a code which inserts data into db. It's working fine now, but I want the title to have a minimum of 4 characters and the body a minimum of 500.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  //get blog data
$title=strip_tags($_POST['title']);
$body=strip_tags($_POST['body']);
$posted_by = $first_name;
$category=$_POST['category'];
$bio = $bio;
$userid=$_COOKIE['user'];
$date = date ('d-M-Y');
if ($title && $body && $category) {
$query = "INSERT INTO blogs (userid, title, body, posted_by, bio, category_id, posted) VALUES ('$userid', '$title', '$body', '$posted_by','$bio', '$category', '$date')";
 $run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 if($query) {
    echo "posted";
  }
  else {
    echo "error";
  }
  }else {
    echo "data missing";
  }
  }
  ?>
```

I tried the code below to put minimum requirements for the title and body, but it echoes the title error message whenever you submit data even when the title contains more than 5 characters.

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   //get blog data
   $title=strip_tags($_POST['title']);
   $body=strip_tags($_POST['body']);
   $posted_by = $first_name;
   $category=$_POST['category'];
   $bio = $bio;
   $userid=$_COOKIE['user'];
   $date = date ('d-M-Y');
   if (strlen($title<5)) {
   echo "Title must be of minimum 5 characters";
   }
   else {
   if (strlen($body<500)) {
    echo "Title must be of minimum 500 characters";
    }
    else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO blogs (userid, title, body, posted_by, bio, category_id, posted) VALUES ('$userid', '$title', '$body', '$posted_by','$bio', '$category', '$date')";
    $run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($query) {
    echo "posted";
    }
    else {
     echo "error";
    }
    }
    }
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question as such deserves an explanation for future readers to the question.

The reason why your code is failing, is that:

```
if (strlen($title<5))
```

evaluates to:

`function($string conditional)`

when the syntax is:

`function($string) conditional`

The manual states:

> int strlen ( string $string )

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Example pulled from the manual:

```
if (strlen($foo) === 0) echo 'Null length is Zero <br>';
```

Plus, as stated in comments. Your query is subject to an SQL injection. It's best to use a prepared statement.

Consult the following links:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: Is mysqli_real_escape_string efficient in preventing such attacks? Is their any option other than prepared statements. Read documents but they are too technical so can you recommend me easiest way to prevent injections . I thought migrating from mysql to mysqli would be enough ;)

Comment: @Harman Have a read at this article on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string - It's rather long, but worth reading. You can use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to a certain extent.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue lies with the conditions you used.

```
if (strlen($title<5))
```

should be

```
if (strlen($title)<5)
```

similarly

```
if (strlen($body<500))
```

to be

```
if (strlen($body)<500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 //get blog data
   $title=strip_tags($_POST['title']);
   $body=strip_tags($_POST['body']);
   $posted_by = $first_name;
   $category=$_POST['category'];
   $bio = $bio;
   $userid=$_COOKIE['user'];
   $date = date ('d-M-Y');
   if (strlen($title) < 5) {
     echo "Title must be of minimum 5 characters";
   }else {
    if (strlen($body) <500 ) {
      echo "Body must be of minimum 500 characters";
     }else {
       $query = "INSERT INTO blogs (userid, title, body, posted_by, bio, category_id, posted) VALUES ('$userid', '$title', '$body', '$posted_by','$bio', '$category', '$date')";
       $run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
      if($query) {
        echo "posted";
      }else {
        echo "error";
      }
    }
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.